# Mysql errors type #1067 - Invalid default value when

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I got more errors when I export my table from Mysql Workbench6.3 and insert into my database by using Phpmyadmin.

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loan`.`tb_banks` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bank_name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `account_name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `account_number` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `banks.user_id = users.id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `loan`.`tb_users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 31
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE INDEX `banks_user_id_index` ON `loan`.`tb_banks` (`user_id` ASC);

SHOW WARNINGS;
```

This is my errors
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not accept TIMESTAMP values that include a zero in the day or month column or values that are not a valid date. 
The **TIMESTAMP** data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. *TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.*

More about this here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html